# Converting DMG to VMDK

Tags: vmware-fusion

How can I convert a DMG into a VMDK file? I had a laptop hard drive which i turned into a DMG. I want to make a VM that uses that drive. How can I turn this DMG into a working VMDK or boot from this DMG for the VM?

Comment: @DKNUCKLES I tried that and I'm getting vmware-rawdiskCreator command not found. Is that something I have to install separately?

Comment: Are you executing the command from within the correct directory? You'll need to execute it where the binary is stored - /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmware-rawdiskCreator

Answer (score 11):

You can do it on Mac OS as also!

The good start point is this [guide](http://hazenet.dk/2013/07/17/creating-a-never-booted-os-x-template-in-vsphere-5-1-part-6/). It gave me the idea about how to do this.
Here are the steps to make **.vmdk** image from **.dmg**.

1. Double click your **hdd.dmg** to mount it.
2. Open Disk Utility and select your **hdd** volume in the left side. Then press *Unmount* button. The volume will become semi transparent.
3. Now press the *Info* button then find disk identifier in a new window. It should be like **disk1**.
4. Open Terminal window. Execute `cd /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/`
5. Run `./vmware-rawdiskCreator print /dev/disk1`. To make sure that it's your source .dmg and it is readable.
6. Then make a linked vmdk via `./vmware-rawdiskCreator create /dev/disk1 fullDevice /Users/yourname/Desktop/hdd-link lsilogic` It will do not a real vmdk but one linked with your dmg data.
7. Run following command to make resizable **hdd.vmdk** with the copy of dmg data. `./vmware-vdiskmanager -r /Users/yourname/Desktop/hdd-link.vmdk -t 0 /Users/yourname/Desktop/hdd.vmdk`
8. After the process successfully completes you can eject your **hdd.dmg** and add the result **hdd.vmdk** to your virtual machine.

You can resize the result vmdk from within your VMWare Fusion app.

Answer (score 1):

On (ubuntu) linux:

First convert to .img:

`dmg2img YOURFILE.dmg`

Then convert to .vmdk:

`qemu-img convert -O vmdk YOURFILE.iso YOURFILE.vmdk`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do this on Windows 10.

First convert to the DMG to an ISO:

```
dmg2img YOURFILE.dmg YOURFILE.iso
```

Then convert that ISO to VMDK:

```
qemu-img convert -O vmdk YOURFILE.iso YOURFILE.vmdk
```

You can write the VMDK to a physical partition with [Paragon Hard Disk Manager Premium](https://www.paragon-software.com/business/hard-disk-manager/) and boot your OS.